# Calling method from another method, no extension method accepting a first argument of type

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a method inside my API Controller and I am trying to call a method from a class, but I get this error:

```
Error   1   'System.Collections.Generic.List<MvcApplication1.Models.UpdateClass>' does not contain a definition for 'PostScheduledTasks' and no extension method 'PostScheduledTasks' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MvcApplication1.Models.UpdateClass>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) \\psf\Home\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MvcApplication1\MvcApplication1\Controllers\UpdateController.cs    18  18  MvcApplication1
```

I am using the my models like so:

```
using MvcApplication1.Models;
```

and this how I am calling the method inside the API Controller

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class UpdateController : ApiController
    {
        private List<UpdateClass> cells;

        [HttpPost]
        public dynamic Post([FromBody]List<UpdateClass> item)
        {
            item.PostScheduledTasks(item);
            return item;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the method inside the class:

```
public void PostScheduledTasks(List<UpdateClass> cells)
{
}
```

but I get that error and red underline under `item.PostScheduledTasks(item);`what do I have to do to fix this?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Why do you have a method that both operates on an instance and takes a collection of other instances?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error clearly states, `List<T>` has no such method.

You probably want to call the method on every item in the list using a loop.

Comment: @user979331 You can update your parameter to be plural, then use a foreach statement to loop over all the items in the list. Inside the foreach block, call your extension method.

Answer (score 0):

Just call

```
PostScheduledTasks(item);
```

---

If this method is declared inside of some class, named `Class`, then you want to make it `static`, and you want to call it like this:

```
Class.PostScheduledTasks(item);
```

Declare it inside of `Class` like this:

```
public static void PostScheduledTasks(List<UpdateClass> cells)
{
}
```

Comment: I get an error, `Error 1 The name 'PostScheduledTasks' does not exist in the current context \\psf\Home\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MvcApplication1\MvcApplication1\Controllers\UpdateController.cs 18 13 MvcApplication1`

Comment: Where is that method declared? Inside the controller, or inside of the `UpdateClass` class?